# Calculate how much time passed comparing WordPress comment and current time

Tags: date-time, timestamp

I'm building a WordPress plugin. I need to show time like Twitter - how much time ago the comment was made etc. Is there a way doing this?

Suppose someone comments 1 hour ago should be visible `1 hour ago` and it should be precise to `1 second ago` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using PHP.

Here's [a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916189/1743124) from @arnorhs:

```
$time = strtotime('2010-04-28 17:25:43');

echo 'event happened '.humanTiming($time).' ago';

function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}
```

### WordPress' way

And actually there are many. But WordPress has a built-in function since its version 1.5.0 that would be handy for WordPress plugin development:

```
<?php human_time_diff( $from, $to ); ?>
```

Show comment's elapsed timing from now would be simple like:

```
echo human_time_diff( get_comment_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) .' ago';
```

#### Reference:

- [`human_time_diff()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff) - WordPress Codex